# Jquery mobile href link dont load new page

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

i'm a web devoper from Italy...I have a problem with loading with href
example:
i have one.html with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <title>dkrMobile</title>
    <!--caricamento librerie-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- LOGIN -->
<div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div style=" text-align:center">
            <img style="width: 70%;" src="http://www.laboncloud.it/dkrmobile/css/images/logdkr.png">
        </div>
        <form action="#pageFile">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="userNameLogin">
                    Username
                </label>
                <input name="" id="userNameLogin" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="passwordLogin">
                    Password
                </label>
                <input name="" id="passwordLogin" placeholder="" value="" type="password">
            </div>

            <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-transition="fade" href="two.html" data-prefetch="trues">
                Login
            </a>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the two.html with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <title>dkrMobile</title>
    <!--caricamento librerie-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tolito-1.0.5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tolito-1.0.5.min.css" />

    <!--css userinterface-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.css" />




</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="loadingPage">
    <div data-role="content">
    <h1>caricamento di tutti i contenuti in corso</h1>
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-transition="fade" href="#pageFile">skip</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pageFile">
    <div data-role="content">
    <h1>dueeee</h1>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- FILE-->

</body>
</html>
```

now if tap on login - the two.html will no be loaded.

want a demo?
[here the demo](http://www.laboncloud.it/dkrmobile/one.html)

if I click on skip in two.html dont show nothing (if I refresh the page it start work).

the only way is data-ajax="false" ? why?

Comment: I'm not sure how correct this is but it works for me, where every page is actually a div inside one html file, so linking to page two would be linking to the div with data-role set to "page" and id set to "two"

Comment: it should work normally with `ajax` enabled `data-ajax=true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an error. To understand this problem you must understand how jQuery Mobile works.

Multi **`HTML`** template can't be mixed with multi page template. For example when  working with several **`HTML`** pages, only first one can have more then one page. When jQuery Mobile loads other **`HTML`** files it will strip HEAD (we dont need it because first **`HTML`** HEAD content is already loaded into the DOM) and it will load ONLY first page it can find in a file, every other page will be discarded.

**`data-prefetch`** will not help you here. Also you are initializing it incorrectly, data-prefetch attribute don't have a value, it is just **`data-prefetch`**, example:

```
<a data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-transition="fade" href="two.html" data-prefetch>Login</a>
```

If you want to find out more how jQuery Mobile handles multiple HTML and multiple page templates or what are they take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** or **[THIS](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)** one. To be transparent they are my personal blog articles. Everything you need to know can be found there.

Basically solution to your problem would be to have all pages inside a single **`HTML`** file, or you should brake two.html into two separate **`HTML`** files. you decide what is a best solution for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
but i have a another question, is safe use login inside multipage layout?

Comment: If you are creating a hybrid  mobile app then answer is yes (it is safe) but if you are creating desktop web application then it is not safe. Even greasemonkey plugin can skip login page. Of course this is not a big problem if you have also a server side logic that can check if use is loged or not.